# ESAPI logger when implemented for class extending SqlMapClientDaoSupport gives class cast exception

Tags: esapi

We are using ESAPI logger as per resolution for a flaw reported by Veracode.  When we changed the logger for class which extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport it gave class cast exception. The reason is SqlMapClientDaoSupport has a protected data member which is org.apache.commons.logging logger. Is there a way we can use esapi loggers in the classes which extend classes having org.apache.commons.logging?

Comment: Did you specify ESAPI's logger factory in your logger config?

Comment: @avgvstvs no I have not done this. Can you explain what are the value which needs to be updated in the configure?

Comment: Esapi is unfortunately hard-coded to use log4j.  http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/reference/Log4JLogFactory.html  this is 2.0.1 documentation but it applies to 2.1.0 as well.